# Как работают конкретные Generic, если в базовом классе стоит ограничение на базовый класс

Tags: .net, generics

Есть такой тестовый код:

```
 public  class DictBase
    {
        public int Val;
    }

    class Dict1 : DictBase
    {
        public int GetVal()
        {
            return Val;
        }
    }
    class ConvertBase<T> where T : DictBase, new()
    {
        public T _dict;

        public ConvertBase()
        {
            _dict = new T();

        }

        public void GetSome()
        {
            var t = _dict.Val;
        }
    }

    class Convert1 : ConvertBase<Dict1>
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
            var t = _dict.GetVal();
        }
    }
```

Интересует класс Convert1.

А конкретно, каким образом я без приведения типов могу вызывать методы у _dict, которые определены в `Dict1`, если в базовой реализации `ConvertBase` у меня у T стоит `DictBase` класс.

Делается неявное преобразование до конкретного класса?

Я ожидал, что будут доступны методы и поля только о `DictBase`.

Comment: В базовой реализации ConvertBase у Вас  T стоит не только DictBase, но и new(). Поэтому "могу вызывать методы у _dict, которые определены в Dict1"

Comment: Если new убрать, то тоже работает.

Comment: Можно пример без new()? А то не взлетает https://ideone.com/Zb28Yj

Comment: Про ошибку без new я знаю, так как не получится создать экземпляр класса. Тем не менее, если убрать new и заменить на createinstance, то к методам все равно можно достучаться.

Comment: @JaponDemon, спасибо. Оформите как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответы есть по этому вопросу, например отсюда   [professorweb.ru C# Ограниченные классы](http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level11/11_4.php):
"Ограничение на базовый класс гарантирует использование только тех аргументов типа, которые поддерживают указанный базовый класс. Это означает, что для любого ограничения, накладываемого на базовый класс, аргумент типа должен обозначать сам базовый класс или производный от него класс. Если же попытаться использовать аргумент типа, не соответствующий указанному базовому классу или не наследующий его, то в результате возникнет ошибка во время компиляции."